# Limit evaluation with integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

> Evaluate the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 n^2x(1-x^2)^n dx$$

**My Proof:**

We may look at $n$ as a constant and evaluate the integral $\int_0^1 x(1-x^2)^ndx$ (I already moved out the $n^2$). From here we integrate by parts;

$$\int_0^1 x(1-x^2)^ndx = x \frac{(1-x^2)^{n+1}}{n+1}|_0^1 - \int_0^1 \frac{(1-x^2)^{n+1}}{n+1} dx = 0 - \frac{1}{n+1} \int_0^1 (1-x^2)^{n+1}dx = -\frac{1}{n+1} - ...$$

If I continue, something not very pretty happens. Is that even the preferable way of evaluating the limit?

Comment: make the substitution, $x \to \sqrt{x}$ then $\displaystyle n^2\int_0^1 x(1-x^2)^n dx = \frac{n^2}{2}\int_0^1 (1-x)^n\,dx = \frac{n^2}{2n+2}$

Comment: @r9m, How did you take an $n^2$ out?

Comment: If we substitute $x\to \sqrt t$ then we have $\int_0^1 (1-t)^{n+1} \frac{dt}{2\sqrt t}$.

Comment: you are forgetting a $\sqrt{t}$ inside the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \sqrt{t}(1-t)^n\frac{\,dt}{2\sqrt{t}} = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 (1-t)^n \,dt = \frac{1}{2n+2}$

Comment: before passing the limit, $n^2$ is as good as a constant. sure it can be pulled out of the integrand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $t = x^2$ then $dt =2x dx$ and the integral becomes

$$\frac{n^2}{2}\int_{0}^{1}(1 - t)^n dt = \frac{n^2}{2}\Bigg(-\frac{(1-t)^{n+1}}{n+1}\Bigg|_{0}^{1}\Bigg) $$

Comment: Can you explain how did you get to the LHS?

Comment: Sure, which part?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to prove that the limit is $+\infty$, IMHO, is to prove that over the interval
$$I_n=\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\right]$$
the function $f_n(x) = x(1-x^2)^n$ satisfies:
$$ f_n(x) \geq \frac{C}{\sqrt{n}} $$
for some absolute constant $C>0$. Since $f_n$ is non-negative over $(0,1)$, the previous inequality gives:
$$ \int_{0}^{1} n^2 f_n(x)\, dx \geq C n.$$

Answer (score 1):

Express the integral in a form by which [Laplace's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) may be applied.  That is, rewrite the integral as

$$I(n) = n^2 \int_0^1 dx \, x \, e^{n \log{(1-x^2)}} $$

Most of the contribution from the integral takes place in the neighborhood about $x=0$, say, $x \in [0,\epsilon]$.  Thus we may Taylor expand the log about $x=0$ to get

$$I(n) = n^2 \int_0^{\epsilon} dx \, x \, e^{-n x^2 +O(n x^4)} $$

Note that we may assume $\epsilon = O\left ( n^{-1/2}\right )$.  Thus $n x^4 = O\left ( n^{-1}\right )$, and the exponential may be expanded.  Further, we may expend the integration limits to $[0,\infty)$ with exponentially small error.  Thus,

$$I(n) = n^2 \int_0^{\infty} dx \, x \, e^{-n x^2} \left [ 1+O\left ( \frac1{n}\right ) \right ] =\frac{n}{2}  +O\left ( 1\right ) $$

The limit is $\infty$.